# Trying to solve $tuu'= -1-u^2.$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking for the solution the the ODE
$$tuu'= -1-u^2.$$
This problem came up in a book on differential equations that I am working through out of personal interest, so it's not  homework or anything. I tried the following approach. First I want to look for a solution to $tuu'= -u^2$ giving
$$\frac{u'}{u}dt =- \frac{dt}{t}$$
This gives $\ln u = -\ln t = \ln \frac{1}{t}$ so that $u = \frac{C}{t}$. The second part $tuu'= -1$ gives
$$uu'dt =- \frac{dt}{t}$$
which has as its solution $u = \sqrt{\ln\left(1 \over t^{2}\right) +D}$. Now the total solution to the original DE is
$$u = \frac{C}{t} + \sqrt{\ln\left(1 \over t^{2}\right) + D}$$
The initial value given for this problem is $u(0) = 2$. Now I dont see how I can even fill in $u(0)$ because we would be dividing by $0$. I am sure I messed up the integration somewhere. I also noted that another solution to the DE is given by $u=0$ or $u=i$,  though both these dont satisfy the initial value either. However, this leads me to believe that my method of solving is not right and that I missed possible solutions. As is stands now I would be forced to conclude ta $C=0$ but then I still haven't solved it.

Here is the original question:

> Problems 1–10 are the same initial-value problems as in the previous exercise set. This time use Heun's method with $h=0.1$. Compare the approximate solutions obtained by Heun's method with the approximate solutions obtained with Euler's method. In Problems 1–6 compare the Heun approximation with the exact solutions.
>
> 6. $tuu'=-1-u^2,\quad u(0)=2$

Comment: How is this a PDE? Is $u=u(t)$?

Comment: Where is the p in this pde?

Comment: $$\text{It might be easier if you replace $u$ by $y=u^2$. We then have $y'=2uu'$. Hence,}$$
$$tuu' = -1-u^2 \implies ty' = -2-2y \implies\dfrac{dy}{1+y} = -2\dfrac{dt}t \implies \ln(1+y) = -2\ln(t)+c$$

Comment: Ah my bad, the P should indeed be an O. Sorry about this.

Comment: You are approaching the DE as if it were linear, which it isn't.

Comment: @anorton Isn't that an answer?

Comment: @Slugger: Are you sure that is the IC they gave $u(0) = 2$?

Comment: $Amzoti yes I am sure... I thought I had solved the problem and then I realized the IC didnt make sense with my answer..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put $y=u^2 \implies y' = 2u\,u'$. This gives us the following:

$$tuu' = -1-u^2 \iff t(2uu')= -2 - 2u^2 \implies  ty' = -2-2y$$

This gives us  $$\dfrac{dy}{1+y} = -2\dfrac{dt}t \implies \ln(1+y) = -2\ln(t)+C $$ $$\iff \ln(1 + u^2) = -2\ln(t) + C$$

Now, the initial value $u(0) = 2$ cannot possibly be correct, as our equation is undefined at $t = 0$. Perhaps a typo?.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, to confirm I will upload a picture of the question so you can see that the IC is indeed $u(0) = 2$. Nonetheless thanks for showing how to solve the DE without the initial condition!

Comment: I added a picture of the question in my original post. Now it's true that $u(0)=K$ is undefined for any $K$ right, the solution is just undefined there. So $u(0)=0$ wouldnt solve it either. Must be a mistake in the book I guess..

Comment: You're welcome, and yes, you're correct: $u(0)$ is undefined. Must be a misprint.

Comment: @amWhy: Needs another TU +1